# Closing a JFrame without it still running

Tags: timer, dispose

Titling this was awkward, but basically I'm trying to close a JFrame that allows the user to change their password.  I know to use the dispose() to close it, but I have a delay timer so the user can see feedback that their password was changed before closing the JFrame.  In my initial testing, I forgot to end the delay timer, so when it opened the programs main frame, it continued to open more and more of the program's main frame until I close the program.  I then obviously went in and stopped the timer.

This has told me something that kinda worries me, that when disposing the frame, it's still running code.  This worries me, it makes me worry that there's a chance that the user could break something or the program could begin to lag with long use if code is still running in the background unnecessarily. Is there a way to actually end the code of the JFrame when its disposed, or is stopping the timer itself the only answer here?

In this case I'm assuming that stopping the timer will stop any background code from running, but if the frame is still active, it makes me worried about the possibilities with other frames that have more interactivity that are being closed and reopened.

EDIT:

I should have explained better. For the actual frame's closing option, I have it as `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` so that the user can't close it without saving their new password or cancelling the password change.

In the save button function, I have:
`delayTimer.start();`

And for the actual timer:

```
if (e.getSource() == delayTimer)
    {
        new MainFrame();
        this.dispose();
        delayTimer.stop();
    }
```

Comment: Ideally, you should stop any `Timers` you start before you close the GUI.  Having said, that, be sure to set your `JFrame` `setDefaultCloseOperation` to `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: I should have explained better.  For the actual frame's closing option, I have it as   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE); so that the user can't close it without saving their new password or cancelling the password change.

In the save button function, I have:
delayTimer.start();

And for the actual timer:
if (e.getSource() == delayTimer)
  {
   new MainFrame();
   this.dispose();
   delayTimer.stop();
  }

Comment: I'd stop the timer, then dispose of the `JFrame`, and finally `System.exit`, but that's just me.